# default argument value for break

Tags: php, html, control-structure

Can anybody tell whats the default argument value for `break` in control structures instead of `break 1 , break 2 ,..`
**Example :-**

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){  
   for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++){
      if($j == 4){
          break;
      }else{
          echo $i+$j."<p>";
      }
   }
}
```

In the above example i used `break` without arguments.Then which value it will take for that..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default argument value for `break` is `1` (ie. innermost control structure). See also: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php